# how to get JSON response covered by XML tag?

Tags: android

please tell me how to get **JSON** response covered by **XML** tag?

```
<string>[
  {
    "value": "America",
    "id": "1898"
  },
  {
    "value": "Afghanistan",
    "id": "546"
  },
  {
    "value": "China",
    "id": "119"
  },
  {
    "value": "Bhutan",
    "id": "1884"
  }
]<string>
```

Comment: like <string>json file </string>

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Parse xml first, and then parse json.

Comment: i want to call a web service which like as ,

Comment: how i parse xml and json please tell me in detail.and i only want to get the city name from that.

Comment: and there are only one xml tag,so how can i convert to json ?

Comment: Hi yours problem is fully solved , find out the code below!!

Comment: Please inform if the question is solved else we can do more!!

Answer (score 1):

hi please find the solution as follows, use below code

```
String jsonData = null;
    XmlPullParserFactory factory;
    try {
        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();

        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        AssetManager manager = getAssets();
        InputStream stream;

        stream = manager.open("data.json");

         xpp.setInput(new StringReader (getStringFromInputStream(stream)));
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                System.out.println("Start document");
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                System.out.println("End document");
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                System.out.println("Start tag " + xpp.getName());
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                System.out.println("End tag " + xpp.getName());
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                System.out.println("Text " + xpp.getText());
                jsonData= xpp.getText();
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //parsing json
    try {
        JSONArray jarray=new JSONArray(jsonData);
        for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++){
            JSONObject jobject=jarray.getJSONObject(i);
            String value=jobject.getString("value");
            String id=jobject.getString("id");
            System.out.println("value " + value);
            System.out.println("id " + id);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the getStringFromInputStream method is as follows

```
private static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();

}
```

for solving yours problem i just put yours given data at asset folder with name data.jason later you can get this data from web services.

```
<string>[
  {
    "value": "America",
    "id": "1898"
  },
  {
    "value": "Afghanistan",
    "id": "546"
  },
  {
    "value": "China",
    "id": "119"
  },
  {
    "value": "Bhutan",
    "id": "1884"
  }
]<string>
```

Comment: i am sure that the asked problem is solved as i wrote this code  and checked , anyway, where it is coming logs please, put an another question at stackoverflow for that and also if this problem is solved please accept the answer that it will be useful for others as well!!

Comment: i want to get the city name from each parsed data and fill in my listview ?

Comment: dude there is no city in yours given data only value which is a country and an id associated with that, please put another question for that

Comment: ya i am sorry there was a value and i only want to fill values name in the listview.

Comment: please put another question with list view code what you are using and close this question as the asked problem is solved and accept it as the basic asked problem is solved!!

Comment: ah dude please send code at stackoverflow with problem

Comment: but just i want to create them while extending Activity so ?

Comment: i do not know what you are expecting?? please put the question if you have a problem

Comment: Sir, it is compulsory Into Hashmap Declaration we pass only 2 parameter and both are string?

Comment: it depend on yours chice, what you are expecting please visit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: it is all about key value pair, please have a lookhttp://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashmap_class.htm , still you did not accept the answer, please accept as the solution is done what you asked in this question!!

Comment: ok. so i want to get only one String from the json so i writes Hashmap<string> right na?

Comment: Hashmap is all about key value pairs so have a key and a corresponding value!!

Comment: tell me list of websites name which is used to working on Android online project ?